# how to return to the beginning of a function of a random text generator?

Tags: javascript, generator

I have built this random text generator using an array, however the user can only click the button every 30 seconds and is disabled for this duration. 
when an items from the array has been displayed and after the disabled function has finished, how to fade back to display the question "What is your name?"

```
function GetValue() {
    var myarray= new Array("Item1", "item2", "item3" );
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
} 

$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("button").removeAttr("disabled");      
        }, 30000);
    });
});
```

```
<!-- html--> 
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" href="#" class="btn btn-block tellme"  onclick="GetValuegirl();" > generate text </button>

<p id="message"  >What is your name?</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var question = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;

function changeTextAndFade($element, text){
 $element.fadeOut( function(){
   $(this).text(text).fadeIn();
  })
}

function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array("Item1", "item2", "item3");
  var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  changeTextAndFade($("#message"), random);
}

$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
      changeTextAndFade($("#message"), question);
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" href="#" class="btn btn-block tellme" onclick="GetValue();">generate text</button>
<p id="message">What is your name?</p>
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the fade, how would one implement that?

Comment: My answer has how you can do it. Hide it first then show.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. You don't need your extra click event handler.

```
function GetValue() {
    var myarray= new Array("Item1", "item2", "item3" );
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    $("#message").html(random);
    $("button").prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        //don't use removeAttr, this completely removed the attribute fromt the element. meaning it cant be true.
        $("button").prop('disabled', false);        
        $("#message").hide(0).html('What is your name?').fadeIn();
    }, 30000);
} 

<!-- html--> 
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" href="#" class="btn btn-block tellme"  onclick="GetValue();" > generate text </button>

<p id="message"  >What is your name?</p>
```